# How can I detect the user who makes changes on a shared folder?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have a shared folder in AD environment. The shared folder contain may sub folders. Different Users Groups have different rights on sub-folders. I want to monitor the shared folder for changes (Create, Rename, Change Content, Delete) and log them. Also I want to log even the user who makes the changes.
How can I detect the user who makes changes on a shared folder in vb .NET?

Some help please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try FileSystemWatcher to monitor the dir 
http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/Tutorials/Controls/FileSystemWatcher.html